# How do I can check input string is a number or is input string containing some given name in C

Tags: c

I am making a `C` program to check is input string have some given number or input string is a number. If number then it is `int` or `float` or `double`.
I am new in `C`. So please don't make me fun if I made any mistake in my code. Please. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
char str[100];
    printf("Enter Your Input:\n");
    scanf("%s",&str);
    if(strcmp(str, "John") == 0 || strcmp(str, "smith") == 0 ||
       strcmp(str, "kat") == 0){
        printf("Name\n");
    }
    else if(str == anynumber){ //I am facing problem here. so please help me about this

        printf("number\n");
    }
else if(str = double or float){// help me here to

}


return 0;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Try to [convert the string to a number](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol). If it fails or not all of the string was converted, you know it was not a number. There are functions for [converting strings to floating point numbers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) a well.

Comment: you can check the string char by char in a loop, using any of available `is` functions, like `isdigit`, `isalpha`, ... Also you can search the string for a given substring using the `strstr` method.

Comment: Research `strtol(), strtoimax(), strtoumax(), strtod(), strtold(), etc`.  Input like "123...100_digits...456" may look like an integer, fit in a `double`, but not fit in an `int, long long`.  Input like "0x123" is that a zero with invalid following text or a nice hexadecimal input for `int`.  This issue is simply read the line of user input as a string and then parse it various ways to see if it meets your criteria for `double, int, unsigned`.  It may match more  than one.

Comment: This is a minor variation on a commonly asked question — it usually appears a bit later in the academic year (January through May), though  The difficulty, as ever, is finding the right duplicate(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot packed into your question as far as (1) do we have a string? or (2) was it a number? and (2a.) if it was a number, was it a floating-point number? or (2b) was it an integer value? and unasked, but (3) do we have characters that follow a number entered by the user?

All these questions can be answered by starting off attempting a conversion to `double` with `strtod`. `strtod` takes two arguments. The first `nptr` a pointer to a string containing a number, and `endptr` a pointer to pointer to char that upon conversion of digits in in the string is set to *one character after* the last digit converted (or set to `nptr` if no digits were converted). That right off the bat answers whether the user entered a number at the beginning of his (or her) input.

The validation is not done. If digits were converted, you still need to check `errno` to validate the conversion was to a valid number in the range of `double`. If the conversion is fine, then you need to check whether there is actually a *fractional part* to the floating-point number of if a whole number was entered. (a simple cast is used below, but you can completely validate the fractional part existence with `modf` that allows checking for `NaN` or positive/negative infinity)

Finally, regarding number input, you need to check whether `endptr` is pointing to the *nul-terminating* character or a `'\n'`. Otherwise, additional characters remain following the number in `str` (beginning at `endptr`).

If none of the above applies, the user input did not start with a number and is a string.

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for strtod  */
#include <string.h>     /* for strlen, strcmp */
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef BUFSIZ          /* if you need a constant, define one */
#define BUFSIZ 4096     /* don't skimp on buffer size */
#endif

int main (void) {

    char str[BUFSIZ] = "", *p = str;    /* p for strtod endptr */
    long longnum = 0;
    double dblnum = 0.0;
    size_t len = 0;

    printf ("Enter your input: ");
    if (fgets (str, BUFSIZ, stdin) == NULL) {   /* validate read */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input or user canceled.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    errno = 0;
    dblnum = strtod (str, &p);          /* attempt convert to double */
    if (p != str) {                     /* digits were converted */
        if (!errno) {                   /* a valid conversion took place */
            longnum = (long)dblnum;     /* trim fractional part */
            if (longnum != dblnum)      /* do we have a double? */
                printf ("you entered a floating-point: %f\n", dblnum);
            else
                printf ("you entered an integer value: %ld\n", longnum);
            if (*p && *p != '\n')   /* characters follow number */
                printf ("characters exist following number: %s", p);
        }
        else
            perror ("strtod failed");

        return errno ? 1 : 0;
    }

    /* we have a string, now trim the trailing '\n' before comparison */
    len = strlen (str);                 /* get str length */
    if (len && str[len - 1] == '\n')    /* check last char '\n' */
        str[--len] = 0;                 /* overwrite with nul-character */
    else    /* warn if input too long */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: input too long.\n");

    printf ("input was not a number: %s\n", str);   /* it was a string */
    if (strcmp (str, "John") == 0 || strcmp (str, "smith") == 0 ||
        strcmp (str, "kat") == 0)
        printf ("the input matched a name: '%s'\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

A string input:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_str_or_num
Enter your input: my dog has fleas.
input was not a number: my dog has fleas.
```

A floating-point (whether you read as double or float is up to you):

```
$ ./bin/fgets_str_or_num
Enter your input: 123.456
you entered a floating-point: 123.456000
```

An integer value:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_str_or_num
Enter your input: 123
you entered an integer value: 123
```

A number followed by more text:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_str_or_num
Enter your input: 123.456 - that's the number of fleas.
you entered a floating-point: 123.456000
characters exist following number:  - that's the number of fleas.
```

An input matching your test:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_str_or_num_names
Enter your input: John
input was not a number: John
the input matched a name: 'John'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `atoi` and `atof` functions from the cstdlib header file.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Note that if the conversion fails zero is returned, so you need special case handling in case of a zero.

There are other ways to do this: you can use streams or [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), just search from "string to number conversion C++" or something similar

Comment: That's why I rather recommend `strtol` and `strtod`, as those have built-in validation.

Comment: Yeah, there are million different ways to do this

Comment: @ventsyv, the OP's question has a C tag, no C++.